# What are the antonyms of ob and prae?

Tags: word-request, preposition, antonym

I learned that the antonym of ante is post, both of which were born dual to each other.

If I understand correctly, ob and prae mean the same or related to ante. What are their antonyms?  post isn't born dual to them. What words were born dual to them?

Comment: Is there a reason to think any words were "born dual to them"?

Answer (score 4):

("born dual to each other" is strange phrasing. All these prepositions were inherited from Proto-Italic, which inherited them from Proto-Indo-European.)

*ante* and *prae*, in their basic meanings, are synonyms, they both mean spatial "in front of, before" and temporal "before". Antonym of both, in these meanings, is *post* (spatial "behind", temporal "after, since").

*ob* has different basic meaning: "toward(s), to, in the direction of". Antonym of *ob* in this meaning is *ex* / *ē*.

A rarer meaning of *prae* is "because of" and this also happens to be a rarer meaning of *ob*.

Comment: Thanks. How would you rephrase "born dual to"?

Comment: @Tim Well, what is it supposed to mean?